# Cannot access to Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I am keep getting this error constantly whenever I try to access my Firebase Console. While I am working, suddenly the page stops working and when I refresh the page, this error pages shows itself. And when it shows itself, it stays for hours..

There is a yellow dot in the [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/) that represents Service Disruption in the Console but there is no explanation about the situation.

Because of we can only contact someone from Firebase for just 5 times in a year, I decided to ask here instead.

Do you know anything about this situation or what causes it or how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: You cannot avoid it, if it happens - you'll have to wait. Although, Firebase status is showing disruption in console, I'm not getting any error. You asked this question 13 hours ago, at that time it was 1 AM here in India, I was able to access console at 11:30 PM yesterday so maybe problem started afterwards. Today morning, I opened console around 7-8, it was still working so I guess they fixed it in a few hours. They will add explanation for the problem after they fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a one-time support question for Firebase and not related to programming.